# Looping through a variable which contains []

Tags: php, concatenation

I am trying to create a PHP function that will echo info from a db. My col names look like banana[1], banana[2], apple[1], apple[2], apple[3], and so on.

The function will select the fruit

```
function fruits($fruit){

}
```

and then within that function I'll loop through the fruits.

How do I echo these?

```
echo $fruit[$i];
```

obviously doesn't work.

Pretty basic, but I can't figure out. Concatenation kills me.

```
function ponctuation($section,$sect){

switch($section){
    case 'apple':
        $i=1;
    break;
    case 'banana':
        $i=13;
    break;
}

global $mysql_tablename;
global $FName;
global $Lname;

if(isset($mysql_tablename)){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $mysql_tablename WHERE FName='$FName' AND Lname='$Lname'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo '<form method="post" action="ponctuation.php?'.${$section.$sect}.'_valider">';
echo '<ul>';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ponct_enonces` WHERE `section`='$section' AND `sect`='$sect'");
while($row_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if($row_q['enon']==0 && $row_q['senon']==0){
        echo '<h2>'.$row_q['enonce'].'</h2>';
    }
    if($row_q['enon']==1){
            echo '<h3>'.$row_q['enonce'].'</h3>';
            echo '<textarea rows="3" cols="100" name="'.$i.'" wrap="physical">' . $row[$section[$i]] . '</textarea>';
    }
    if($row_q['senon']==1){
            echo '<h4>'.$row_q['enonce'].'</h4>';
            echo '<textarea rows="3" cols="100" name="'.$i.'" wrap="physical">' . $row[$section]. '</textarea>';
    }
    $i++;
    }
echo '</ol>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Valider"/>';
echo '</form>';
}
```

}

The code is a little ugly, and some vars have French names, other have English names.

Comment: What's wrong with `echo $fruit[$i]`?

Comment: Don't hav enough information to help you.  Maybe posting the code fragment where you say you're looping the fruits array may help.

Comment: Did you mean `$row['banana[1]']=blabla...`, `$row['banana[2]']=blabla..`? If so, just do `foreach($row as $fruit) echo $fruit;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

col names won't be expanded into PHP array structures for you, e.g.

```
SELECT fruit[1], fruit[2], ...., fruit[100]
```

will give you the equivalent of

```
$row = array(
   'fruit[1]' => someval,
   'fruit[2]' => someval,
   ...
);
```

if you want to iterate those, you'll have to get ugly:

```
$fruit = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $fruit[$i] = $row['fruit[' . $i . ']'];
}
```

which begs the question of... why? This is a horrible data structure to be using. Properly normalizing it into a 'fruit attributes' sub-table would save you this trouble, and also allow you to have `n` attributes, rather than the fixed 1..100 range or whatever it is you have.

Comment: So if I don't want to get ugly, how should I call my cols?

Comment: Do some [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on it

Comment: I'm sorry... normalization? Still pretty new to PHP.

Comment: Should I call them apple1, apple2 instead? That's what I first did, but then I was told to call them apple[1] and so on, that it would be easier to handle.

Comment: database concept. follow the link and do some reading. doesn't have anything to do with php, other than you're using php to talk to a database.

Comment: `apple[1]` would work in an html form with php, creating an array in $_POST or $_GET for you. but in a database, it's a whole different ball game.

Comment: I'll do the reading, thanks :)

What if I want to set apple[1] as the value of a form input?

echo '<textarea rows="3" cols="100" name="'.$i.'" wrap="physical">' . $row[$fruit[$i]] . '</textarea>';

This is what I have so far, and it's not working. (I'm looping through $i.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to loop over all the columns in a row, you can use `fetch_array`:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array();

// loop over columns
for ($i = 0, $count = count($row); $i < $count; $i++)
    echo $row[$i];
```

That way, you won't have to worry about the column names. I might be misunderstanding your question, though.

Comment: Why call `count()` for every iteration ?

Comment: @Zaffy - Well, to be fair, a row with five columns wouldn't be a huge performance hit (unless it's fetching many rows, that is). But you're right, I should (and did) optimize it.